# GT.M, any experience with it?

Tags: nosql, mumps, gtm-database

Looking for NOSQL engines I found about GT.M here:
http://www.slideshare.net/robtweed/gtm-a-tried-and-tested-schemaless-database

At first look good, with SQL ODBC support. But I wonder if exist real experience with this? Somebody have use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have experience with it myself, but there is a list of some users of this database here: http://fisglobal.com/Products/TechnologyPlatforms/GTM/index.htm

Answer (score 3):

GT.M is a very flexible engine that allows for NoSQL operations, but also is fast in cacheing disk to memory, as well as extensive enterprise level support.

I suggest you read the discussion by Rob Tweed at http://www.mgateway.com/docs/universalNoSQL.pdf
which would probably help you understand capability without jargon.

Answer (score 2):

From [GT.M's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GT.M) :

> GT.M is used as the backend of their FIS Profile banking application, and it powers ING DIRECT banks in the United States, Canada, Spain, France, Italy and the UK. It is also used as an open source backend for the Electronic Health Record system WorldVistA and other open source EHRs such as Medsphere's OpenVista.

and

> GT.M is predominantly used in healthcare and financial services industry. The first production use of GT.M was in 1986 at the Elvis Presley Memorial Trauma Center in Memphis, Tennessee.

From [History of GT.M](http://www.fisglobal.com/products-technologyplatforms-gtm-historyofgtm) :

> GT.M is licensed for use at over 1,000 institutions worldwide, ranging from small, community healthcare facilities and large teaching hospitals to some of the largest financial institutions in the world.

Also, from a [recent presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/QueEsBhaskar/120426-1-introgtm?goback=.gde_1786567_member_112644174) made by K.S. Bhaskar :

1. System of record for the two largest real time core banking systems in the world as we know of:

   - Production database sizes of a few TB
   - Serving around 10,000 concurrent online users + ATMs, voice response unit, web and mobile access
   - 1000s of online banking transactions/seconds with full ACID properties.
2. Increasingly used in health care for for electronic health records
3. Operating database for at least one multi-sourced "big-data" project.